# Scrollbar in custom section of account page

Tags: visualforce, scrolling

I am sure this is a fairly simple question but when I go to embed a custom VF page with a scrollbar, into an account page, the scrollbar does not show up and the page gets cut off. Does anyone know why this is happening? When it is not embedded, the scroll bar shows up. Could it be something to do with the account page's markup? [image: Missing Scroll Bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page layout, ensure that "Show Scrollbars" is checked for your Visualforce Page item.

[image]